# Hor to create a route on SUMO

Tags: simulator, sumo

I took this pre-defined route from the Erlangen map in SUMO. I'd like to know how I can create a second route, but in the opposite direction.

Another question is, can I specify which lane the cars will travel on the road?

`<routes> <vType id="vtype0" accel="2.6" decel="4.5" sigma="0.5" length="2.5" minGap="0.5" maxSpeed="14" color="1,1,0"/> <route id="route0" edges="-39539626 -5445204#2 -5445204#1 113939244#2 -126606716 23339459 30405358#1 85355912 85355911#0 85355911#1 30405356 5931612 30350450#0 30350450#1 30350450#2 4006702#0 4006702#1 4900043 4900041#1"/> <flow id="flow0" type="vtype0" route="route0" begin="0" period="3" number="80"/> </routes>`

Thanks!